# What are the best sources to learn CakePhp for beginners?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to learn where developers here learned CakePhp. Cookbook is good at most points but not clear enough to teach I think.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps duplicated.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420048/any-tips-on-how-to-learn-cakephp-for-a-beginner

Comment: Oh you are right. I looked for this topic but couldn't find. Sorry ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The blog tutorial in the cookbook is the best place to start.
- After that, modify the blog and read the manual. It takes time - there is no quick way.
- Try to read and understand the API:
- Give yourself a target like **build a blog that does what *I* want not what *Wordpress* wants**
- Join the CakePHP group on Google: http://groups.google.co.uk/group/cake-php?hl=en

And try to put as much effort into the backend as you do the front end!

Comment: Thanks for advices Leo. I have completed blog tutorial and my mind more clear now. I will do the rest of your sayings. I have already planning a project to develop. But couldn't decide where should I start yet ^_^ Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Believe me man,**cookbook is good enough**.

Anyway,there's a another [tutorial in IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-cake1/index.html) may worth a reading.

Answer (score 0):

http://mark-story.com/
http://teknoid.wordpress.com/
http://variable3.com/blog/category/programming/cakephp/

try these blogs

Answer (score 0):

The best resource is the book.  It has everything you need.  When in doubt you can pop in here or the IRC channel #cakephp at irc.freenode.net

Answer (score -1):

This is list articles about cakephp 2.x for beginners.

> http://tutscode.com/tag/cakephp

I hope help you.